# Distribution of unique elements in a sample of non-uniform probability.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

I have a random variable $X$ that takes on 4 discrete values $x_1, x_2,x_3,x_4$ with probabilities $a,b,c,d > 0$

I sample m values from $X$ and would like to know the probability of the number of distinct elements $D_m$ in the sample. So the event $\{D_m=d\}$ means that there are exactly d distinct elements in a sample of size $m$

For example, $P(D_1 = 1) = 1$ as our sample will have one element and it is distinct and $P(D_m = 1) = a^m + b^m + c^m + d^m$. To make the analysis simpler I only care about the case $m\geq 3$ and the result $P(D_m=2)$

I believe we can do the following:
$$P(D_m = 2) = \sum_{k = 1}^{m-1} P(k \text{ values of } x_1 \text{ and } m-k \text{ values of }x_2) + P(k\text{ values of }x_1\text{ and }m-k\text{ values of }x_3) + ...  $$

I believe that is valid but it doesn't give a particularly nice closed form solution as you now need to go over all 6 possible combinations of $x_1, ..., x_4$. I would settle for a non-trivial upper bound to this question if the result is intractable.

Each term has the form $\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}P(k \text{ values of } x_1 \text{ and } m-k \text{ values of }x_2) = \sum_{k=1}^{m-1}a^kb^{m-k}$ which has a value of $\frac{a^mb - ab^m}{a-b}$ since its the geometric sum of $\frac{a}{b}$ with coefficient $b^m$.
I dont know if we can upper bound each of these terms by the difference between the max and the min of $a,b,c,d$ to get a nice enough upper-bound

Please let me know if this is valid, and if you know any particular closed form solution or a non-trivial upperbound.

Comment: You're absolutely right Michael, I wrote that part before I revised my definition of $D_m$, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: You are neglecting the ${m \choose k}$ terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of $a,b,c,d$ use $a_1, a_2, a_2, a_4$. We know $D_m \in \{1,2,3,4\}$ and
$$P[D_m=1] = \sum_{i=1}^4 a_i^m$$
Here I will edit my answer for a better result on the $\{D_m=2\}$ case (which follows the idea from the OP discussion and also the Ragno answer): For $i \in \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ define $A_i$ as the event that at least one of the $m$ picks is of type $i$. Let $A_i^c$ denote the complement of $A_i$. For shorthand use notation $$A_1A_2=A_1\cap A_2 \quad, \quad A_1A_2A_3^c=A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3^c$$
and so on.

**Claim:** $P[A_1A_2A_3^cA_4^c] =(a_1+a_2)^m - a_1^m-a_2^m$.

**Proof:** Define events
\begin{align}
D&=\{\mbox{only types 1 or 2}\}=A_3^cA_4^c\\
E&=\{\mbox{only type 1}\}=A_2^cA_3^cA_4^c\\ 
F&=\{\mbox{only type 2}\}=A_1^cA_3^cA_4^c\\
G&=\{\mbox{at least one type 1, at least 1 type 2, no other types}\} = A_1A_2A_3^cA_4^c
\end{align}
Then $E, F, G$ are disjoint and $D=E \cup F \cup G$, so
$$ \underbrace{P[D]}_{(a_1+a_2)^m} = \underbrace{P[E]+P[F]}_{a_1^m+a_2^m} + P[G]$$
$\Box$

The probabilities for the other events associated with having exactly 2 types, such as $P[A_1A_2^cA_3A_4^c]$, have a similar structure. Thus
\begin{align}
P[D_m=2] &=P[A_1A_2A_3^cA_4^c]+...+P[A_1^cA_2^cA_3A_4]\\
&=\sum_{(i,j)\in S} [(a_i+a_j)^m-a_i^m-a_j^m]
\end{align}
where
$$ S = \{(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,3), (2,4), (3,4)\}$$

---

To find $P[D_m=3], P[D_m=4]$ for the general case we have
$$ P[D_m=4]=1-P[D_m=1]-P[D_m=2]-P[D_m=3]$$
It suffices to find $P[D_m=3]$. We get
\begin{align}
P[D_m=3]&=P[A_1A_2A_3A_4^c] + P[A_1A_2A_3^cA_4] \\
&\quad + P[A_1A_2^cA_3A_4]+P[A_1^cA_2A_3A_4]
\end{align}
Now we have the disjoint union:
\begin{align}
\{\mbox{only types 1, 2, or 3}\} &= A_1A_2A_3A_4^c\\
&\quad \cup\{\mbox{only type 1}\} \cup \{\mbox{only type 2}\}\cup \{\mbox{only type 3}\}\\
& \quad \cup \{\mbox{exactly 2 types from 1,2,3}\}
\end{align}
Also
\begin{align}
&P[\mbox{only types 1, 2, or 3}] =(a_1+a_2+a_3)^m\\
&P[\mbox{only type $i$}] = a_i^m\quad \forall i \in \{1,2,3\}
\end{align}
Thus
\begin{align}
&P[A_1A_2A_3A_4^c]\\
&=(a_1+a_2+a_3)^m-a_1^m-a_2^m-a_3^m \\
&\quad- P[A_1A_2A_3^cA_4^c]-P[A_1A_2^cA_3A_4^c]-P[A_1^cA_2A_3A_4^c]\\
&=(a_1+a_2+a_3)^m-a_1^m-a_2^m-a_3^m\\
&\quad - [(a_1+a_2)^m -a_1^m-a_2^m]\\
&\quad - [(a_1+a_3)^m - a_1^m-a_3^m]\\
&\quad - [(a_2+a_3)^m-a_2^m-a_3^m]\\
&= (a_1+a_2+a_3)^m + a_1^m+a_2^m+a_3^m\\
&\quad -(a_1+a_2)^m-(a_1+a_3)^m-(a_2+a_3)^m
\end{align}
and the remaining terms $P[A_1A_2A_3^cA_4]$, $P[A_1A_2^cA_3A_4]$, $P[A_1^cA_2A_3A_4]$ have a similar structure.

---

In the special case $a_i=1/4$ for all $i \in \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ then
\begin{align}
&P[D_m=1]=4(1/4)^m\\
&P[D_m=2]=6[(1/2)^m-2(1/4)^m]\\
&P[D_m=3] = 4[(3/4)^m + 3(1/4)^m-3(1/2)^m]
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply michael, could you please show me the set algebra you performed to derive the probability of $D_m=2$?, I can't quite figure it out. Specifically for $P[A_1A_2A^c_3A^c_4]$

Comment: I have edited my answer to explain that step.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are completely right. I dont think there is a nicer close form for the exact probability, for an upper bound you can use the following one:

For simplicity I assume that $a\geq b \geq c \geq d $. Let $\beta$ denote $\max\{\frac{b}{a}, \frac{c}{a},\frac{d}{a},\frac{c}{b},\frac{d}{b},\frac{d}{c}\}$, then

\begin{equation}
    \mathbb{P}(D_m=2)\leq 6 a^m \frac{\beta-\beta^m}{1-\beta} \leq 6a^m (m-1)
\end{equation}

Proof:

\begin{equation}
     \frac{c^m b - c b^m}{c-b}= b^m \frac{\frac{c}{b}-(\frac{c}{b})^m}{1-\frac{c}{b}}\leq a^m \frac{\beta-\beta^m}{1-\beta} 
\end{equation}

Note that $f(\beta)=\frac{\beta-\beta^m}{1-\beta}$ is an increasing function in $[0,1)$, and $\lim_{\beta\rightarrow 1} f(\beta)= m-1$. The bound is exact when $a=b=c=d$.

Comment: thanks for your reply, can you explain further how you derived the last inequality from your proof?

Comment: Yes, Im using that $b^m\leq a^m$, and  $c/b\leq \beta$, and since $f(\cdot)$ is an increasing function $f(c/b)\leq f(\beta)\leq m-1$.

Comment: I see, makes sense, thank you

Comment: This neglects the $m \choose k$ factors, though indeed summing over the 6 terms for the $\{D_m=2\}$ case is simpler than the inclusion-exclusion I originally suggested for that case.